# Apache Cordova VS2015 - Clear Cache on remote machine

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, caching, visual-studio-cordova, apache-cordova

I've started using Apache Cordova tools for VS2015 and using the remote build tool on a Mac to run iPhone simulators. When debugging the solution I'm seeing a lot of old JS files that are clearly not being updated on the Macs cache. It's equivalent to the browser not getting the latest version of a JS file and using the one in cache as the debugger stops on lines that are no longer or have moved.

How do I reset the cache on the Mac (remote device) so that it will load all of the latest files from my project?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting the issue. If you do a clean build from VS then it should create a completely fresh project with no relation to the previous one and hence should use the latest version of your files.

I would like to know more about the old JS files that you are seeing, because typically each build should be using your most recent versions.

Let me know, what you find.

SOak